# how to insert sakila db data into mysql with docker-compose?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin, dockerfile

I want to be able to create database and schema, and insert data into MySQL with using docker-compose file.

The database in question is the famous sakila database.

I have created a git repo to do the aforementioned and the git repo is [this](https://github.com/emireadcode/create-db-schema-insert-data-with-docker-compose)

When I run the command below

```
sudo docker-compose up --build --remove-orphans
```

I have to wait for a period of time for the data to show on phpmyadmin but I realized most database tables are empty.

So I have tried to add MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=0 to the phpmyadmin service with hope that it will run until all insert statement will finish running.

```
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - mysql
    ports:
        - 8081:80
    environment:
        - MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=0
        - PMA_HOST=mysql
        - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```

But I have no luck with my effort and some tables do not have data yet.

Please I need help on how to make the insert data work instantaneously and completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that insert data that involves hundreds of thousands of insert statements will take time to complete; in other words, the speed depends on the number of records to be inserted.

On the other hand, foreign key constraint conflict causes the insert data script to exit abruptly thus resulting in some tables having no data but when the command 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;' is added to the insert data script

```
USE sakila;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Insert into film
(`film_id`,`title`,`description`,`release_year`,`language_id`,`original_language_id`,`rental_duration`,`rental_rate`,`length`,`replacement_cost`,`rating`,`special_features`,`last_update`)
Values
('258','DRUMS DYNAMITE','A Epic Display of a Crocodile And a Crocodile who must Confront a Dog in An Abandoned Amusement Park','2006','1',NULL,'6','0.99','96','11.99','PG','Trailers','2006-02-15 05:03:42.000')
;
```

Everything worked successfully.